# How to make a new instance in an object method?

Tags: java

How to create a new instance and put that reference memory in the object that called the method? Like this:

```
class A {
  void method() {
    this = new A(); //didnt work
    new A(); //didnt work
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new A();
    obj.method(); //new instance
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. A variable can be reassigned to a new object, but an object cannot be changed to a new object.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looks like yet another case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Please use [edit] option and explain what you *really* want to achieve.

Comment: Why not simply do `A method() { return new A(); }` and then `obj = obj.method();`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer - you can't. `this` is a constant, and cannot be reassigned from within a method.